# Correlation Test loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a data frame with p values and estimates that compares one gene to many different expression markers. My cor.test works when I use it on only one expression but when I try to loop it it breaks and gives me this error "  'x' and 'y' must have the same length".
I am wondering how to get this loop to work and build the data frame.

Below is what I am running through my loop and the code for the loop.

```
M3 <- ads$mean

Expression <- c("Exp1","Exp2","Exp3")

for (i in seq_along(Expression))
{
  corr<-cor.test(M3, Expression[i], method = "pearson")
  cor_df<-data.frame(Expression = Expression[i],pvalue = corr$p.value, 
 cor = corr$estimate)

 }
```

Comment: `Expression` is a character vector  (`Expression <- c("Exp1","Exp2","Exp3")`) so to calculate correlation with `Expression[i]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Expression is calling names of numeric variables from my data frame. Does that not work properly when put into the cor test? It works when I do not put it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if `Exp1`, `Exp2`, and `Exp3` are columns in a data frame (`df`) then you can use something like this:

```
corr <- cor.test(M3, df[ ,Expression[i]], method = "pearson")
```